# Multi-object create/update/delete? Use select SOAP APIs from REST client?

Tags: soap-api, rest, transaction

I have a client calling various SF REST APIs.

So far so good.  Unfortunately (and inexplicably in my opinion), object create, update, and delete operations can handle 1 object per REST API request, however, which has some serious drawbacks (e.g. unnecessary network chatter/latency for each object, inability to do everything in 1 transaction, etc).

I don't want to have to create custom services in SalesForce -- as the client should be generic to any SalesForce installation.  And I don't want to rewrite everything in SOAP -- REST is much more appropriate overall.

Is there a way I can just make multi-object create, update, and delete calls from my REST client, e.g. using bare-bones SOAP calls for precisely these calls and passing the access token already established for the REST calls?

I really don't get why these capabilities are excluded from the REST API itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the new [batch resource that was added in Summer 15](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_api_rest.htm).

> `vXX.X/composite/batch`
>
> The Batch resource lets you execute a sequence of independent subrequests. For example, you can update the name on an account and get the account’s field values in a single request.
>
> ```
> {
>     "batchRequests" : [
>     {
>     "method" : "PATCH",
>     "url" : "v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ",
>     "richInput" : {"Name" : "NewName"}
>     },{
>     "method" : "GET",
>     "url" : "v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ"
>     }]
> }
> ```
>
> The response contains the status codes of each subresponse and the responses themselves.
>
> ```
> {   
>  "hasErrors" : false,
>  "results" : [
>     {     
>     "statusCode" : 204,
>     "result" : null
>     },{
>     "statusCode" : 200,
>     "result" : { Account attributes }
>     }] 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to.   Here's a excerpt from the REST API documentation

> **Upserting Records and Associating with an External ID**
>
> If you have an
> object that references another object using a relationship, you can
> use REST API to both insert or update a new record, and also reference
> another object using an external ID.
>
> **The following example creates a new record and associates it with a
> parent record via external ID.**
>
> It assumes the following: A
> Merchandise__c custom object that has an external ID field named
> MerchandiseExtID__c.
>
> A Line_Item__c custom object that has an external
> ID field named LineItemExtID__c, and a relationship to Merchandise__c.
>
> A Merchandise__c record exists that has a MerchandiseExtID__c value of
> 123.
>
> A Line_Item__c record with a LineItemExtID__c value of 456 does not exist. This is the record that will get created and associated to
> the Merchandise__c record.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/

Your other option is to use the Bulk REST API, which is discussed in another thread: [INSERTING MULTIPLE RECORDS USING SALESFORCE REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21516/inserting-multiple-records-using-salesforce-rest-api)

Comment: But if I (1) have no knowledge of an external id [again, this is to be generic] and (2) want to do this to multiple objects in one call to SalesForce, ideally as 1 all-or-nothing transaction, how does upsert solve anything for me?  Upsert is still a single-object API in SF REST.

As for the bulk API, I want *synchronous* creation of multiple records here.